# 文字とWingdingsフォントの絵文字のUnicodeの間で変換するライブラリは無いか

Tags: java, unicode

[Wingdingsフォント](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingdings)の絵文字を普通の文字に、普通の文字をWingdingsの絵文字(Unicode)に変換をしたいです。例えば`!`を`\u270F`(✏)に、`\u9986`(✄)を`"`に変換してほしいです。

この機能を実装したライブラリを探してみたのですが見つかりませんでした。この機能を含んだライブラリはあるのでしょうか。知っておられる方は教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: 例として挙げられている鉛筆マークですが、Unicode7.0になってよりWingdingsに近い字形の \u1F589 が追加されたみたいですね。

Comment: Unicodeは[ここ](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings.html)から取ってきました。@unarist 質問の意図とは少し違ったので修正しました。

Comment: 作ってみます。手間がかかりますが…